# Adding a new Class File to my project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a GUI for plotting a reporting:

GUI:

```
package aatmPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;



import org.jfree.util.ShapeUtilities;




public class GuiAATM extends javax.swing.JFrame {

...
private void reportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


report Report =  new report();

setReportLog("Report Generated Successfully\n");
}    
}
```

I created another project and tested it which works fine to generate a report. Now When I am adding that class to my GuiAATM project , (where the user when clicks report button should generate the report) I am getting below error:

```
log4j:WARN Parsing warning 2 and column 38
log4j:WARN URI was not reported to parser for entity [dtd]
log4j:WARN Parsing warning 2 and column 38
log4j:WARN missing system ID, using log4j.dtd
log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [jar:file:/D:/Glaswegian/Java/DynamicCharts/dynamicreports-3.1.0-project-with-dependencies%20(1)/dynamicreports-3.1.0/dist/dynamicreports-examples-3.1.0-sources.jar!/log4j.xml].
gnu.xml.dom.DomEx: The operation violates XML Namespaces.
More Information: xmlns is reserved
Node Name: #document
    at gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.createAttributeNS(DomDocument.java:589)
    at gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.createAttribute(DomDocument.java:561)
    at gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.defaultAttributes(DomDocument.java:456)
    at gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.createElementNS(DomDocument.java:440)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.DomConsumer$Handler.startElement(DomConsumer.java:602)
    at gnu.xml.dom.Consumer$Backdoor.startElement(Consumer.java:203)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.EventFilter.startElement(EventFilter.java:570)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer.startElement(ValidationConsumer.java:1177)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.startElement(SAXDriver.java:836)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseElement(XmlParser.java:1037)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDocument(XmlParser.java:416)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:167)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)
    at gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory$JAXPBuilder.parse(JAXPFactory.java:186)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:612)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:711)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.defaults.Defaults.<clinit>(Defaults.java:42)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.design.transformation.TemplateTransform.getPageHeight(TemplateTransform.java:663)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.design.transformation.PageTransform.transform(PageTransform.java:44)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.design.base.DRDesignReport.transform(DRDesignReport.java:132)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.design.base.DRDesignReport.<init>(DRDesignReport.java:107)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.design.base.DRDesignReport.<init>(DRDesignReport.java:99)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReportDesign(JasperReportBuilder.java:260)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.getJasperParameters(JasperReportBuilder.java:287)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:298)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.show(JasperReportBuilder.java:327)
    at aatmPackage.report.build(report.java:70)
    at aatmPackage.report.<init>(report.java:26)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM.reportButtonActionPerformed(GuiAATM.java:1214)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM.access$400(GuiAATM.java:34)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM$5.actionPerformed(GuiAATM.java:968)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomElement.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseExportFonts(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:317)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:285)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:193)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:308)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.show(JasperReportBuilder.java:327)
    at aatmPackage.report.build(report.java:70)
    at aatmPackage.report.<init>(report.java:26)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM.reportButtonActionPerformed(GuiAATM.java:1214)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM.access$400(GuiAATM.java:34)
    at aatmPackage.GuiAATM$5.actionPerformed(GuiAATM.java:968)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

My report.java file is:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package aatmPackage;

import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;


import net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.Templates;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.StyleBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.FontBuilder;

public class report {
  public report() {
        build();

    }

    private void build() {  
            StyleBuilder boldStyle         = stl.style().bold();
           // FontBuilder  boldFont = stl.fontArialBold().setFontSize(12);
            Color MAROON = new Color(122, 5, 5);
            StyleBuilder titleLineOne = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                    (HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).setFontSize(15).setForegroundColor
                    (MAROON);
            StyleBuilder titleNextLine = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                    (HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).setFontSize(12).setForegroundColor
                    (MAROON);

            StyleBuilder bodyTitleStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                    (HorizontalAlignment.LEFT).setFontSize(12);

            StyleBuilder bodyStyle = stl.style().setFontSize(11);

            StyleBuilder signatureStyle = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                    (HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

            StyleBuilder footerLeft         = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                   (HorizontalAlignment.LEFT).setForegroundColor
                    (MAROON) ;
             StyleBuilder footerRight         = stl.style(boldStyle).setHorizontalAlignment
                   (HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).setForegroundColor
                    (MAROON) ;

            //BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1200,1200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
           BufferedImage img = null;
try {
   // img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Hysteresis.png"));
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Hysteresis.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
       BufferedImage logo = null;
try {
   // img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Hysteresis.png"));
    logo = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Logo.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
        try {
            report()//create new report design
                         // .setColumnTitleStyle(boldStyle)
                         // .setColumnStyle(boldStyle)
                          .highlightDetailEvenRows()
              .columns(//add columns

                col.column(null,"Col_1",  type.stringType())
                                .setStyle(bodyStyle),
                col.column(null,"Col_2",  type.stringType())
                                .setStyle(bodyStyle)
                                )
                           .summary(

        cmp.verticalList()
          //  .add(cmp.filler().setStyle(stl.style().setTopBorder(stl.pen2Point())).setFixedHeight(10))                    
            .add(
             cmp.text("\n"),                   
             cmp.filler().setStyle(stl.style().setTopBorder(stl.pen1Point())),
             cmp.text("\nHYSTERISIS PLOT\n").setStyle(bodyTitleStyle),
            cmp.text(" 1.\n").setStyle(
                                bodyStyle),

           // .add(cmp.image(getClass().getResourceAsStream
             //     ("D:/Hysteresis.png")).setFixedDimension(300, 300))

            cmp.horizontalList()             
            .add(cmp.image(img).setFixedDimension(350, 250),
            //cmp.text("ANALYSIS\n").setStyle(bodyTitleStyle),
            cmp.text("Right Lobe Change:160.04%\n").setStyle(bodyStyle),
            cmp.text("Left Lobe Change: 35.38%\n").setStyle(bodyStyle),
            cmp.text("Hysteresis Change: 81.50%\n").setStyle(bodyStyle)), 
            //cmp.filler().setStyle(stl.style().setTopBorder(stl.pen1Point())),
            cmp.text("REMARKS\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n").setStyle(bodyTitleStyle),
            cmp.text("Doctor Signature").setStyle(signatureStyle))
    )
              .title(

                                cmp.horizontalList()
                                .add(
                                cmp.image(logo).setFixedDimension(70, 70),
                                cmp.verticalList()
                                .add(
                                cmp.text(" Ltd").setStyle(titleLineOne),
                                cmp.text(", ").setStyle(titleNextLine),
                                cmp.text("Mobile +").setStyle(titleNextLine))
                                )
                               /* cmp.horizontalList()
                                .add( cmp.text("Allahabad Bypass Varanasi").setStyle(boldCenteredStyle))
                              */
                                .newRow()
 .add(cmp.filler().setStyle(stl.style().setTopBorder(stl.pen2Point())).setFixedHeight(10))

                                )//shows report title

                              //  .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY())//shows number of page at page footer
                                .pageFooter(
                                Templates.footerComponent,
                                 //cmp.text(" \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
                               // + " ")
                                cmp.horizontalList()
                                .add(cmp.text("Emsol Software Solution").setStyle(footerLeft),
                                cmp.text("copyright: gauravbvelex@gmail.com").setStyle(footerRight))
                                )

              .setDataSource(createDataSource())//set datasource
              .show();//create and show report
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("Col_1", "Col_2");

        dataSource.add("Name","Sample");
                dataSource.add("Age","26");
                dataSource.add("Sex","Female");
                dataSource.add("Weight","53 Kg");
                dataSource.add("BMI","20");
                dataSource.add("Massage Duration (Mins)","4.5");
                dataSource.add("RPM","26");
                dataSource.add("Doctor Attended","Doctor");
                dataSource.add("Date","24-Feb-2013");

        return dataSource;
    }  
}
```

This report works fine when run as a separate project, then I tried creating a sample jFrame and then added this .java file and run it. When I clicked the button it created the report. But the actual project (which I developed in 20 days GUI and the functionalities) it throws the error shown. I even tried to put the report code in the gui file itself but got the same error. I am not able to resolve the issue.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: first try clean and build ; then try to add it as a library .jar D:\youReprotClassPath\jar -cf name.jar * and if you using netbeans add to libraries of project

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the resolution...

It seems Dynamic Charts uses jFreeChart Libraries. I was manually importing libraries for dynamic Charts as well as jFreeChart.

Resolution was : Delted all libraries and then imported only for dynamic charts.

I guess .xml for both libraries were conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple implementations .jar files for XML parsing (maybe multiples versions of xerces in classpath ?).

gnujaxp.jar also could be the source of the problem.